# systemd initiated Nodejs script can't communicate with SVN

Tags: javascript, node.js, svn, systemd

I have a Nodejs script running on Ubuntu, which serves as an HTTP server (using Express) and when a specific POST is made to the server, it will attempt to log in to SVN and execute an `svn info` command using the following code:

```
svn_info = ["info", server, "--xml", "--non-interactive", "--username", svn_username, "--password", svn_password, "--no-auth-cache"];
output = spawnSync("svn", svn_info, { encoding: 'utf8' });
logger.debug(output.output);
```

This works perfectly as a standalone script using the command line. Executing `nodejs app.js` and sending the appropriate POST, results in the following (path names etc. have been manually replaced here by "labels" enclosed in square brackets):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<info>
    <entry path="my_path" revision="67368" kind="dir">
        <url>https://[svn_server]/[root_path]/[relative_path]/my_path</url>
        <relative-url>^/[relative_path]/my_path</relative-url>
        <repository>
            <root>https://[svn_server]/[root_path]</root>
            <uuid>[UUID]</uuid>
        </repository>
        <commit revision="67334">
            <author>author@domain</author>
            <date>2019-02-07T15:33:15.806240Z</date>
        </commit>
    </entry>
</info>
```

My systemd script, `test_server.service` calls the Nodejs script like so:

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nodejs /home/some_path/app.js

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When the script is started, either through boot or the `service test_server start` command, and the same POST command is made, I see the following in my log file:

```
[2019-02-08T15:25:19.251Z] debug: ,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<info>
,svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://[svn_server]/[root_path]/[relative_path]/my_path'
svn: E000111: Error running context: Connection refused
```

The script is running as root-user, both from the shell and when kicked-off by systemd. I'm struggling to understand what subtle difference could be causing the script to fail when it's executed by systemd.

Comment: Do the SVN server and the client run on the same computer? This looks like a firewall issue.

Comment: No, the server is on another computer (outside of my control). I agree with your theory. It seems that the machine with the Nodejs script behaves differently when it's run through systemd. I don't know whether it's not possible to talk through certain ports when running as systemd or what?

Answer (score 0):

**tldr;**

It transpires that this was nothing to do with the code posted above. It was because the machine running the web-server is on a different network to the machine running the SVN server. The two are only allowed to communicate via a proxy, which needed to be set in the `~/.subversion/servers` file.

**The longer story**

When logged on as "user1", this user had the SVN proxy server correctly set in the `~/.subversion/servers` file. Running `sudo svn info` against the SVN repository worked, presumably because the same `~/.subversion/servers` file was in use.

If I used `sudo -i` (which runs as "root", with all environment variables set as though I were logged-on as "root") I discovered that, sure enough, when using `svn info`, I got back the "Connection refused" error.

After editing the `~/.subversion/servers` file to utilise the correct proxy:

```
[global]
# http-proxy-exceptions = *.exception.com, www.internal-site.org
http-proxy-host = defaultproxy.whatever.com
http-proxy-port = 7000
```

Everything worked perfectly!